# How do I resolve the 500 Internal Server Error in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication, resttemplate, internal-server-error

I am getting the error 500 Internal Server Error in Java

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transformToListClass': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"timestamp":"2020-08-20T20:48:50.993+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while fopping..","path":"/v1/en/E_TEMPLATE"}]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"timestamp":"2020-08-20T20:48:50.993+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while fopping..","path":"/v1/en/E_TEMPLATE"}]

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"timestamp":"2020-08-20T20:48:50.993+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while fopping..","path":"/v1/en/E_TEMPLATE"}]
```

I have opened two spring applications one running on port `8080` and another running on port `8013`.

I am sending a post request as follows from the one in port `8080` to the one in port `8013`:

I am also using basic authentication embedded in the restTemplate headers

```
public ImageDescriptor generateImage(String payLoad, String templateName) {
    try {
        ImageDescriptor descriptor = new ImageDescriptor();

        String MEl = "http://localhost:8013/v1/en";
      String eURL = MEL.concat(Constant.F_SLASH).concat(templateName);

       log.info("payload" + payLoad);

        ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                eURL,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                ncbiService.getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(payLoad),
                Resource.class);
      log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream()));
        descriptor.setInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getBody()).getInputStream());

        convert(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream(), "sherrr.pdf");

        log.info("file is:"+ convert(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream(), "sherrr.pdf"));

        return descriptor;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(" generate image failed " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Below is the service in port 8013, which I am calling in port 8080:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/v1/e")
public class EcrionController {

@Autowired
private FOPService fopService;
@PostMapping(path = "{documentType}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createDocument(@PathVariable DocType documentType, @RequestBody String payload) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Document Type: ", documentType.toString()));
        LOGGER.info(String.format("PayLoad : %s", payload));
        inputStream = fopService.doFOP(payload, documentType);
        InputStreamResource streamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
                .body(streamResource);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error", ex);
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }

}
```

The security service in port 8013 is as follows

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${spring.security.user.name}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.security.user.roles}")
    private String roles;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles(roles);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

How do I get rid of the 500 Internal Server Error in java?